# Depth Buffer on DirectX10 not working

Tags: c++, directx-10, zbuffer

So I'm trying to create a scene in DirectX10 and for some reason my zbuffer(depth buffer) doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code where I set up the Zbuffer:

```
// Initialize the description of the depth buffer.
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

// Set up the description of the depth buffer.
depthBufferDesc.Width = _iScreenWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = _iScreenHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

// Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
if(FAILED(m_pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_pDepthStencilBuffer)))
{
    return false;
}

// Initialize the description of the stencil state.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

// Set up the description of the stencil state.
depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D10_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_LESS;

depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Create the depth stencil state.
if(FAILED(m_pDevice->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_pDepthStencilState)))
{
    return false;
}

// Set the depth stencil state on the D3D device.
m_pDevice->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_pDepthStencilState, 1);

// Initailze the depth stencil view.
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

// Set up the depth stencil view description.
depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

// Create the depth stencil view.
if(FAILED(m_pDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(m_pDepthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_pDepthStencilView)))
{
    return false;
}

// Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline.
m_pDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_pRenderTargetView, m_pDepthStencilView);

// Setup the raster description which will determine how and what polygons will be drawn.
rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = true;
rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D10_CULL_BACK;
rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D10_FILL_SOLID;
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

// Uncomment to turn off back-face culling
//rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D10_CULL_NONE;
//rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D10_FILL_WIREFRAME;

// Create the rasterizer state from the description we just filled out.
if(FAILED(m_pDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_pRasterState)))
{
    return false;
}
```

And here is what it looks like in my scene: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK4I3.jpg

I used the resource ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to step by step me through but am now quite confused as to why it's not working.

Any help would be VERY much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please stop using *doesn't seem to be working*, from the picture, I can't see what's wrong, you should give more details.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what other details to give other then the ZBuffer seems to be simply not working. As you can see in the picture the water is located inside the ponds yet the water is being rendered over the pool. So it's not detecting that the side of the pool is closer and drawing that instead.

Answer (score 0):

1> Your depthBufferDesc and depthStencilViewDesc format should be like:

```
DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT
```

2> And depending on your model, you can try setup rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise to true.

```
rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = true;
```

3> Please check that you viewport has set:

```
ViewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
ViewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
```

4> And you have to check you near clipping plane in your camera. The value have to be greater then zero.